# Communicate with a single-user Ethernet-connected device — OK to use shared LAN?

Tags: networking, ethernet, port, ipv4

I have a workstation that has two network ports. One of them is required to connect the PC to a local area network. The other port is available to accommodate an Ethernet device that I (and nobody else) need to access. I have two options:

1. Leave the device on its default settings (which place it on a different subnet), configure the IPv4 settings for the second port to the same subnet, and connect the device to that port.
2. Update the device's network settings to match the local area network's subnet and connect the device into a network port in the wall.

Will option #1 (connecting two devices directly with an Ethernet cable,
but no hub or switch) even work?

Are there any performance issues that I should be aware of when choosing one of these options?

What do you recommend?

Comment: I reworded your question to make it somewhat less of a broad request for people’s opinions.  (1) Please review and correct any errors I may have introduced. Also, state (2) whether the device can operate at the same network speed as the LAN, (3) what volume of data flow you anticipate between your PC and the device, and (4) whether there are any privacy / security concerns with having the device on the LAN, where it is potentially accessible to others.

Comment: I believe the device can operate at the same network speed as the LAN. The device will be sending about 1KB of data at a time across the network. There are no security issues with regard to having the device on a LAN.

Comment: Also I have tested option #1 and it does work. I can ping the IP address and operate the device successfully.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 1):

Your option 2, where you connect the device to the network which uses
the first adapter, will make the device a part of the general network and
accessible to everyone, but it is by far the easiest option.
You will not be using the second network adapter in this case.

For option 1, where you connect directly two devices without a router
in-between, will likely need an
[Ethernet crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable),
although the devices may be able to communicate with a normal cable,
as you can test.
You will also need to give the device and your computer's
matching network adapter static IP addresses on this new network,
and the devices will need to address each other by their IP address.

Comment: Are there any reasons why I should use one method over the other for better performance?

Comment: This should not be a factor if both adapters have similar performance.